# What's the `socket` param of a CPU?

Tags: cpu, processor-socket

When I configure KVM virtual machine OS xml file:

[image]

you see, there gives CPU configuration:

```
<cpu>
    <topology sockets="1" cores="2"  threads="1">
</cpu>
```

what's the socket to a CPU?
I can know a CPU have multi cores, and one core can have multi threads. but how about the `socket`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [CPU socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket) is where you place the
CPU on the motherboard. Some computers have multiple CPUs and so require
multiple sockets.

For a virtual machine, one socket with one CPU is entirely enough.
Specifying too many will cause KVM to allocate too many threads that may
slow down the physical computer.